# Matching rows from different tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have these tables with the following columns:

- **Tables**

  - sanit, sanit2
- **Columns**

  - sube, id_pes, approved

I want to find the rows that appears into these two tables. So the rows must have the same valeu for each column.
I tried the following code. But it doesn't work.

```
select sube, id_pes, approved from sanit 
    where  sube in (select sube from sanit2) and 
           id_pes in (select id_pes from sanit2) and 
           approved in (select approved from sanit2);
```

Once I know all the rows that appear in both tables, I'll create a new table using these rows.

Comment: *I'm not quite sure it solves my problem.* This is incorrect query - even when all 3 conditions are TRUE this does not mean that equal values are taken **from the same row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want one subquery.  In MySQL you can use `in`:

```
select sube, id_pes, approved
from sanit 
where (sube, id_pes, approved) in (select sube, id_pes, approved from sanit2);
```

Note that `NULL` values will fail the comparison.

Comment: I guess you should use `exists or cte`  I am not sure that syntax would work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think is pretty much the same that I did, isn't? But the way you did is much cleaver.

Comment: @CarlosVilaca . . . No.  This is quite different from the query in the question.  This requires that all three values in one row of `sanit` appear in a single row in `sanit2`.  Your version doesn't require that.  The matches can be to any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sube, id_pes, approved
FROM sanit 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM sanit2
               WHERE sanit.sube <=> sanit2.sube
                 AND sanit.id_pes <=> sanit2.id_pes
                 AND sanit.approved <=> sanit2.approved );
```

This query will return all matched rows even when some column(s) are NULL.